# A23 MediaCodec API

Tags: android, video-encoding, android-mediacodec

In a Android 4.2, A23 processor, We are trying to implement hardware encoding on the camera using the standard MediaCodec api, but couldn;t figure out what is the correct color format to use, for example, when we use this color format: MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar, this one is the value returned by android api to use, it's supposed to work, the encode inits well, but logcat issues error

E/omx_venc(  108): do not support this format: 21

We have tried many different formats, none works well.

```
/**
 * Video encoding is done by a MediaCodec.
 */
protected void prepareHwEncoder() throws RuntimeException, IOException 
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Video encoded using the MediaCodec API with a buffer");     

    int encoderColorFormat = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar;
    // .COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar;

    mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate);  
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, encoderColorFormat);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);
    mEncoder.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);


}
```

any example code that works on the camera is highly appreciated.

Comment: A23 pusblished a native sample here, http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/SDK/A23-v1.0/unpacked/A23/android/hardware/aw/AWcodecTest/, but not sure how this can be done using standard MediaCodec api.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the codec to determine what color formats it supports.  Typical color formats are listed [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q5).  Note that all supported MediaCodec color formats have the U/V planes reversed relative to the Camera color formats.

You can find an example of this in the CTS [EncodeDecodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest) -- see `selectColorFormat()`.

Unfortunately, in Android 4.2, there's [no guarantee](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q9) that a reasonable color format is supported.

Comment: I should mention that MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar (21) is the color format returned by selectColorFormat(), so it seems this is the desired color format to feed, but it still throws error saying this color format is not supported. Using other color formats don't even  get that far.

Comment: Ugh.  It's entirely possible that MediaCodec is not usable on this device.  I assume this is with "video/avc"?

Comment: yes, the mime type is video/avc, seems AllWinnder does not implement the java mediacodec stuff